# React Native: Create custom child node in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As I am new to the firebase and React, I appreciate your help as I have tried everything almost.

Following is my data structure in firebase.

[image]

When I add new **Beverage** type i.e. **Milk** with its fields i.e. with nested nodes and data to **Products**, firebase generate child node based on random number. Please help me and let me know how I can create custom child nodes with no text as mentioned in the data structure. in actual I have ready json as mentioned below and want to add new beverage type with its details as mentioned below in json.

```
"Id" : 1,
"Milk" : {
  "Id" : 2,
  "Imported Milks" : {
    "Frosted Milk" : 20,
    "Milk Up" : 10
  },
  "Local Milks" : {
    "Cow Power" : 5,
    "Milk Man" : 3
  }
}
```

following is my code:

```
       let product = "Milk";
       const dbUpdate = await firebase.database().ref("Products");
       //this.state.selectedCategory is Milk
       await dbUpdate.child(this.state.selectedCategory).set(
            {
             product:
                    {
                        Id: item.Id,
                        "Imported Milks": {
                                "Frosted Milk": 20,
                                "Milk Up" : 10
                            }                               
                    }
            }
        );
```

I just made some changes to my code. It worked but set is deleted all previous records and added only new one.

```
       let product = "Milk";
       const dbUpdate = await firebase.database().ref("Products");
       //this.state.selectedCategory is Milk
       await dbUpdate.set(
            {
             this.state.selectedCategory:{
                    product:
                    {
                        Id: item.Id,
                        "Imported Milks": {
                                "Frosted Milk": 20,
                                "Milk Up" : 10
                            }                               
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new beverage with a key you specify yourself, you can do:

```
firebase.database().ref("Products/Beverages/Beers").child("Lagunitas").set(1);
```

So the important thing here is that we don't call `push` (which would generate a ID), but instead specify your own key (in the call to `child()` in this case).

---

If you want to set an entire JSON object, that'd be:

```
firebase.database().ref("Products").set({
  Beverages: {
    Beers: {
      Id: 1,
      "Imported Beers": {
        Bella: 20,
        LoveBug: 5
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

If you want to use the value of your `product` variable in the path to *update* a path in the database, you can do:

```
let product = "Milk";
const dbUpdate = await firebase.database().ref("Products");
                                                // 
await dbUpdate.child(this.state.selectedCategory).update({
  [product]: //  Use [] to use the value of the variable
     {
         Id: item.Id,
         "Imported Milks": {
                 "Frosted Milk": 20,
                 "Milk Up" : 10
             }                               
     }
 });
```

This will set the `Milk` key in `selectedCategory`, but leave other child keys unmodified.

---

If you want to perform a deep update of one key in a branch, you can also use a path as the key. So for example to add the two items to `Imported Milks`, but leave any other values unmodified, you'd do:

```
firebase.database().ref("Products").update({
  "Beverages/Milk/Imported Milks/Frosted Milk": 20,
  "Beverages/Milk/Imported Milks/Milk Up" : 10
})
```

Comment: I want to add another type of Beverages i.e. Milk this time instead of Beer

Comment: `firebase.database().ref("Products/Beverages/Milk").child("Skim").set(1)`?

Comment: I have updated my question to make it understandable. so it will be creating nodes Milks, Imported Milks and Local Milks dynamically and will be posting its data. So what I want to do is to post entire json under the Beverages and create db like shown in picture.

Comment: I added an example of setting a JSON node. Hope that helps, but if not: did you try anything already? Can you show the code of what you already tried?

Comment: Thanks Frank for getting back to me on this. I have edited question and added my code.

Comment: I added two more sections, but it feels like a moving target at this point. I recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure we have a better chance of proving a concise answer in one go.